# replacing an element of a tuple by another element stored in a list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list:

```
replace_by=['a1','b1','c1','d1','e1']
```

I also have a list of tuples in the type of

```
main_list=[('a',[]),('b',[]),('c',[]),('d',[]),('e',[])]
```

My main goal is to replace the first elements of each tuple in the main_list namely a,b,c,d,e by the corresponding elements in the replace_by list namely a1,b1,c1,d1,e1.

I would appreciate if any one could help me with this in a pythonic way! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How is it "corresponding"? by index ? side-note: tuples are immutable, you can't "replace" anything in side a tuple - you can just create a new one!

Comment: Tuples are immutable, so you'd have to use another data structure, or *replace* the tuples rather than changing them. Also, I wonder if you might not want to use something like a map in this instance. It would help if you explained what you're trying to achieve (and gave us an example of the expected output, as @alfasin suggests).

Comment: The tuples are immutable, but not te lists inside them. He could use `main_list[0][1].append(replace_by[1])` and have no problem.

Comment: @ArthurGouveia Right, but I'm not really sure what the OP is trying to achieve (he says 'first elements', which I guess would mean the  strings rather than the lists).

Comment: Yeah. You're right. My mistake.

Comment: Thank you alfsain, SwiftsNamesake and Arthur Gouveia for the quick response and I also had the same query since tuples are immutable, so as suggested by @Josep Valls, I created a new list of my tuples, solved my problem. Thank you everyone for this! Sincerely appreciate this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuples cannot be modified in place. However you can easily create a new version,

```
replace_by=['a1','b1','c1','d1','e1']
main_list=[('a',[]),('b',[]),('c',[]),('d',[]),('e',[])]

new_list = [(replace_by[i],b)for (i,(a,b)) in enumerate(main_list)]
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really "replace" as tuples are immutable but you can still make new tuples using the first element from the `replace_by` list and the second from the original `main_list`.

```
new_list = [(a,b[1]) for a,b in zip(replace_by,main_list)]
```

Comment: This helped me!